# Magento has been hacked

Tags: magento-1.9

a Magento site has been hacked recently. The order created even after I just sign up.

Please Advise.

Thank you.

Comment: I did try disabling any 3rd party extension, change the theme. but still, it creates an order just after signing up.

Comment: Check User Role and its Permission. and check for any strange entry?

Comment: did check that as well. but nothing found any strange entry

Comment: The order created just after signup means? Can add more details

Comment: here's the step I did. 

1. I register as a new customer
2. Magento redirected me to account dashboard. 
3. on my dashboard. I have an order already. even though I didn't make one.

Comment: That's really strange issue.